# Online Logistic Regression by Month with Sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I would like to train a Logistic Regression classifier in online fashion with Sklearn. I know about the 'SAG' or 'SAGA' but I am not sure how to implement this.

Specifically, my goal is to get the algorithm to train on the last t-x months (e.g. x=3) at time t where t is a month in the year. I would want to make a prediction over the set of examples for the following month (time t+1).

Here is my df:

```
X.head()

year    month   age job marital
0   2008    5   56  3   1
1   2008    5   57  7   1
2   2008    5   37  7   1
3   2008    5   40  0   1
4   2008    5   56  7   1

y.head()

0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    0
Name: y, dtype: int8
```

Say I have my clf as in the code below (in this example I have trained it on the entire dataset in batch):

```
clf = LogisticRegression(C=1, max_iter=100, class_weight = 'balanced')

y_pred = clf.predict(X)

cmx = pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix(y, y_pred), 
                   index = ['No', 'Yes'],
                   columns = ['No', 'Yes'])
```

Notice I am not just looking to get a model created for each month in the dataset, but to have a model train itself in an online (minibatch technically) fashion throughout the entire dataset

Comment: What is the question? Please describe where/how your attempt fails to meet your goal.

Comment: Basically, I have a time series data frame and I would like to run a logistic regression in online fashion. I would like to be able to set a month based boundary on the rolling window, and most importantly I would like to be able to assess how my model coefficients are varying in time.